# Can I have 2 subdomains with same ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, subdomain, ssl-certificate

Simple question, can I have in the same machine 2 web applications, running in different subdomains with the same ssl certificate?

ex:

```
m.example.com
z.example.com
```

Same Machine, same IP!

Comment: what webserver?  IIS6, IIS7 and Apache all deal with this a little differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either:

- a wildcard certificate (e.g. `*.mydomain.yy`), although [their usage is discouraged](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2),
- a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names (DNS: `m.domain.yy` and `z.domain.yy`).

For reference, this is documented in [RFC 2818 (section 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) and [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125).

How the web server is then configured to dispatch the request to the appropriate web application depends on which web server you are using (as @Brian said in a comment to your question).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a [wildcard certificate](http://www.verisign.com/ssl-certificates/wildcard-ssl-certificates/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

with a wildcard ssl certificate
http://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/wildcard-ssl.php